# Regular expression let periods in (.)

Tags: regex

My regular expression lets in periods for some reason, how can I keep that from happening.

Rules:

1. 4-15 characters
2. Any alphanumeric characters
3. Underscore as long as it's not first or last

   `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{3,14}`

I don't want "bad.example" for work.

Edit: changed to 4-15 characters

Comment: Currently your regex allows 4-15 characters, and it doesn't allow digits as the first character - are you sure of your specifications? It also doesn't prevent the underscore at the end of the string.

Comment: As ever, this question demonstrates why it's important to provide details like what problem you are trying to solve and which regex dialect / engine and/or hosting application you are using. Read the [tag:regex] tag description, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches `example` as a substring of `bad.example`. Use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to prevent that:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{1,12}[A-Za-z]$
```

Note that (like your regex) this regex also prevents digits from matching in the first and last position - if they should be allowed (as per your specs), just add `0-9` at the end of the character classes.

Comment: I'm getting this warning: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: @AlainGoldman just a minor note :include `\d`  in the first and last group as well :)

Comment: What kind of anchor to use depends on the hosting application and the problem domain. If you don't anticipate multi-line input it doesn't really matter. If you do, how do you want to handle it? It's not clear from your spec. If you want to prevent multi-line input, change the anchors.

Comment: @AlainGoldman: As tripleee said, some anchors behave differently according to the mode they are currently in (which again depends on the regex engine being used - which is why the regex tag wiki says to always include information about the regex engine in the tags). In your case, it won't matter since there is nothing in your regex that would allow a newline character to match. Also, please check your question again - should digits be allowed in all positions in the string or are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{3,14}$
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

It does not match `bad.example` but matches only `example` as your regex allows a character from 4 to 15.See here.

http://regex101.com/r/xV4eL5/5

To prevent it you need to match the whole input and not make partial matches.Put a `^` start anchor and `$` end anchor.
Use

```
\A[A-Za-z0-9][\w]{1,12}[A-Za-z0-9]\Z
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match any alphanumeric at the beginning and end. In the middle it will accept from one up to twelve alphanumerics including an underscore:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d]\w{1,12}[a-zA-Z\d]$
```